# i am getting CrashLoopBackOff error "exec /usr/sbin/nginx", how to resolve?

Tags: angular, docker, kubernetes

This is my docker file

```sh
#!/bin/bash
FROM node:10.8.0 as build-stage
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json /app/
RUN npm install
COPY ./ /app/
ARG configuration=production
RUN npm run build -- --output-path=./dist/out --configuration $configuration
FROM nginx:1.15
#Copy ci-dashboard-dist
COPY --from=build-stage /app/dist/out/ /usr/share/nginx/html
#Copy default nginx configuration
COPY ./nginx-custom.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

I am getting error CrashLoopBackOff. When i try to find the log it says `exec /usr/sbin/nginx: exec format error`. How can i resolve this and get the app running

Comment: Are you potentially building the image on an ARM-based system (like an M1 Mac) but running it on an x86 host, or _vice versa_?

Comment: Why do you have Kubernetes tag?

Comment: @DavidMaze yes, this image is build with M1 Mac, and i am trying to run it on linux kubernetes cluster of x86 host

Answer (score 1):

Try something like adding `--platform=linux/amd64` in your **Dockerfile**

```
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 node:18-alpine as builder
```

Build the image and run it on **K8s**.

it could be due to the building image on Mac or Arm and your K8s cluster is not supporting that architecture.

> The optional **--platform** flag can be used to specify the platform
> of the image in case FROM references a multi-platform image. For
> example, linux/amd64, linux/arm64, or windows/amd64. By default, the
> target platform of the build request is used.

[Doc ref](https://The%20optional%20--platform%20flag%20can%20be%20used%20to%20specify%20the%20platform%20of%20the%20image%20in%20case%20FROM%20references%20a%20multi-platform%20image.%20For%20example,%20linux/amd64,%20linux/arm64,%20or%20windows/amd64.%20By%20default,%20the%20target%20platform%20of%20the%20build%20request%20is%20used.)